# Posting an array of checkboxes from an onclick button event prototype or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, prototypejs

I have a table of rows containing data and a checkbox to the very left. Here is the HTML for one of my rows

(the checkbox):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="records[]" name="records[]" value="1" />
```

As you can see, the row has a checkbox with a name of "records[]", indicating it is an array of values within the records array. Just above my HTML table, I have a button that when pushed, will take the checked records and post it to a new URL. I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Just an FYI, the table and the buttons are not within a form.

Comment: can you post an example on FiddleJS?

Comment: If neither answer answered your question, then this is a sure sign that you need to edit your question and add more code and details. After looking at the other answer, I'm starting to question whether or not we understand what you are wanting to accomplish exactly.

Comment: Im not sure how else to word it. I want to collect the values for the checked boxes and post it to a new page via javascript.

Comment: Ok... Is checkbox A always going to URL A or does checkbox B sometimes also go to URL A?  you mention several actions, but does the same data get sent in the different actions or are each sandboxed? Can you show what code you have so far aside from just the single input box? Can you show how you're trying to submit the data? It doesn't matter if the code works or not, but seeing what you've tried will definitely help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your HTML looks something like what is posted below, where your inputs are within the form, but the table and your buttons are not.

One trick to handling this situation is to bind an onclick event handler to your button element that then invokes the click method of a hidden submit button in the form itself. This effectively "chains" your buttons together.

```
<form action="/yourURL" name="yourForm" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="records[]" name="records[]" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="submitBtn" />

</form>

<table>
    <button id="yourButton" value="click me" />

</table>

$('#yourButton').click(function() {
    $('#submitBtn').click();
}
```

Another method is to just call the submit method of the form object itself:

```
$('#yourButton').click(function() {
    $('[name="yourForm"]').submit();
}
```

Comment: I didnt use a form because there are a number of different actions on the page, not just one. For this example, I need the data to post to an export page. So, I cannot rely on submitting the form. Maybe i can add an onclick event and change the form action within the javascript?

Comment: You know you can have more than one form on a page, right? Just give each form a unique name with its own action url, and then you can access its submit handler through the jQuery DOM methods. If this doesn't answer your question, please please edit your question and add more detail. Pouring through comments trying to understand what you want is less helpful than actually seeing some code in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#tableId input[type="checkbox"]')
```

a little bit of jquery. This will select all chekbox items from table. You can check with .val() method is it cheked.